# AWS application load balancer working only for default path rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I created an alb named demoLoadBalancer with two target groups, namely tg1 and tg2. Both the target groups had ec2 instances running. ec2 instance in tg1 was running an apache server with LandingPage.html in /var/www/html and tg2 had music.html in /var/www/html. I have configured path rules in load balancer. Default path is set to LandingPage.html, /server1/* is set to LandingPage.html and /server2/* is set to music.html. The screenshot is attached below:

[image]

[image]

Now, when i access the default url of the demoloadbalancer, it forwards me to LandingPage.html. But when i try to load the webPage using /server/LandingPage.html it throws 404 error.The images are attached below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: When you copy the DNS name of the ALB and enter in the browser with /server1/LandingPage.html in the URL, are you getting error 404?

Comment: It gives the following error when i try and access /server1/LandingPage.html : "Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at demoloadbalancer-756339062.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com Port 80"

Comment: What was the issue? I am facing same now

Answer (score 0):

The rules wyou have configured for the Path based routing are an Exact Match.

To forward trrafice to /server1/something and /server2/something.

you have to configure a rule for the path with the wildcard like this /server1* and /server2* , This will ensure that the any other information under this path is served for the users properly.

Comment: I think when the ALB forwards traffic to your service, the path remains intact, so need to have this path is your server, for example: /var/www/html/server1/LandingPage.html

Comment: if that was the case, then there should have been an error for default path rule. But that was successful. Look at third image.